# Is there a way to access n when using n-th child without javascript?

Tags: css, css-selectors, pseudo-element

Say for example I have:

```css
#with-index span::after {
    content: attr(data-n);
    position: relative;
    top: -8px;
    font-size: 9px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: red;
}

#without-index span:nth-child(1n)::after {
    content: attr(n);
    position: relative;
    top: -8px;
    font-size: 9px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="without-index">
    <span>Hello</span> <span>World</span>
</div>

<div id="with-index">
    <span data-n="0">Hello</span> <span data-n="1">World</span>
</div>
```

If I put the index as an attribute, I can use `content: attr(data-n)`.  If there a way using `nth-child(1n)` to get the value of `n` to achieve the same effect without having to set any other attribute?

Comment: CSS doesn't know anything about the HTML file it's applied to and does not read data back. So no you can't do anything dynamic with a selector. The options are to track it in HTML as you've done with `data-attr`, use a preprocessor like SCSS/LESS (but even these won't tell you the current one) or use JS to parse the DOM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a CSS counter like this:

```css
#without-index { counter-reset: number -1; }

#without-index span::after {
    content: counter(number);
    counter-increment: number;
    position: relative;
    top: -8px;
    font-size: 9px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="without-index">
    <span>Hello</span> <span>World</span>
</div>
```